# Почему for и forEach работают по-разному?

Tags: javascript

Привет. С недавних пор решил перейти с `for`-цикла на `forEach()`, ибо это действительно удобнее. Особенно при работе с вложенными массивами. Обычно у меня всё работало нормально, то теперь вот произошла какая-то чертовщина. У меня есть функция, которая проходится по обычному массиву и сверяет, есть ли в элементе этого массива значение ключа, которое соответствовало бы отправленной к функции в качестве аргумента переменной:

```
function getDepCountryFlag(dep) {
    airports.forEach((airport) => {
        if(airport.id == dep) {
            return airport.country_code;
        }
    });
}
```

Казалось бы, просто как дважды два. Но вот это дело всё время выдавало мне `undefined`. Я уже было хотел подзабить и оставить это на завтра, но решил на крайняк уже попробовать старый добрый `for`-loop. И мой код чудесным образом перестал отдавать мне undefined и заработал так, как мне и нужно было!

```
function getDepCountryFlag(dep) {
    for(let i = 0; i < airports.length; i++) {
        if(airports[i].id == dep)
            return airports[i].country_code;
    }
}
```

**Вопрос:** я что-то упустил при чтении документации по forEach и он не работает по аналогии с for? Почему давал `undefined`, а `for` заработал?

Comment: `return airport.country_code;` - Как Вы думаете, какая функция здесь  возвращает значение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В этом куске кода:

```js
function getDepCountryFlag(dep) {
    airports.forEach((airport) => {
        if(airport.id == dep) {
            return airport.country_code;
        }
    });
}
```

– Вы делаете **возврат из анонимной callback-функции**, а не из функции `getDepCountryFlag`.

Comment: Ваш ответ с текстом `Вы делаете возврат из анонимной callback-функции, а не из функции getDepCountryFlag` является самым верным. Другие почему-то решили найти другой подход, а не объяснить причину :)

Answer (score 2):

```
function getDepCountryFlag(dep) {
  var found = null;
  airports.forEach((airport) => {
    if (airport.id == dep && !found) {
      found = airport;
    }
  });
  return (found)? found.country_code : null;
}
```

А лучше:

```
function getDepCountryFlag(dep) {
  var found = airports.find((item) => item.id == dep);
  return (found)? found.country_code : null;
}
```

Comment: Я идиот. Спасибо)

Comment: А объяснений-то не будет? Кусок кода - не лучший формат ответа на вопрос "почему".

Answer (score 0):

Если уж ты и реализуешь подобные алгоритмы, то делай это используя не только forEach, но и другие итераторы, например Array.find()

```
function getDepCountryFlag(dep) {
  const airPort = airports.find(airport => airport.id == dep);
  return airPort ? airPort. country_code : null;
}
```

Такой код намного читабельнее и локаничнее

Так же советую в JS всегда использовать строгое сравнение типов `airport.id === dep`, подробно про это можно почитать тут https://learn.javascript.ru/comparison